# Do I need to explicitly use flush() method there?

Tags: java, flush

Do I need there to explicitly `writer.flush()` or not? I think that after leaving `save()` method `writer` may not write data to the `outputStream`

```java
import java.io.*;

public class Test
{
    public int i = 5;
    
    public void save(OutputStream outputStream) throws Exception
    {
        PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(outputStream);
        writer.println(i);
        writer.flush(); // necessarily or not?
    }
}
```

Comment: Not if you close the output stream afterwards at some point.

Comment: It's just a question of when you want to flush the data to the output stream.  Closing the PrintWriter will also flush it, as daniu pointed out.  You will need to flush it somehow at some point in your program, otherwise there's no guarantee that the data will make it to the output stream, but without seeing the rest of your code, it's tough to say whether you need that particular line or not.

Comment: I know that if close outer stream inner stream will also be closed, and know that if don't flush() or close() outer stream data will not be saved. But I don't know if PrintWriter/BufferedWriter or other outer stream sends data immediately to the inner stream. So example can there be a situation when PrintWriter contain data that I send to it and lose it after leaving save() function without sending data to the inner stream if I dont't use close() or flush() functions?

Comment: You can also use the CTOR `PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(outputStream, true);`. The true flag is for autoflush. autoflush is checked and executed each time you call any println() method or use one of the format() methods. They call the internal newLine() method, where autoflush gets checks for and executed. Look at the source code of PrintWriter, there you can see its beahaviour. Best download the Java source code pack and link it in you IDE, you you have easy and direct access to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From `flush` documentation:

> ```java
>  /**
>   * Flushes the stream.  If the stream has saved any characters from the
>   * various write() methods in a buffer, write them immediately to their
>   * intended destination.  Then, if that destination is another character or
>   * byte stream, flush it.  Thus one flush() invocation will flush all the
>   * buffers in a chain of Writers and OutputStreams.
>   *
>   * <p> If the intended destination of this stream is an abstraction provided
>   * by the underlying operating system, for example a file, then flushing the
>   * stream guarantees only that bytes previously written to the stream are
>   * passed to the operating system for writing; it does not guarantee that
>   * they are actually written to a physical device such as a disk drive.
>   *
>   * @throws java.io.IOException
>   *          If an I/O error occurs
>   */
> ```

Therefore if you need to guarantee the bytes are written to the next stream, call it.

Please take a look at `checkError` which according to its documentation:

> ```
> * Flushes the stream if it's not closed and checks its error state.
> ```